# Canonicalization node not closed properly

Tags: php, soap, canonicalization, wsse, xmlseclibs

TL;DR
`<CanonicalizationMethod>` node winds up with too many children when using wse-php

I'm using wse-php to sign a SOAP request. I've used plain XmlSecLib to sign Saml in the past, but when using wse-php to construct my security node and sign a specific header element, the `node ends up as the parent node to the`` node, which is incorrect, and causing my soap request to fail.

Example of the incorrect structure after signing:

```
<ds:signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:signedinfo>
    <ds:canonicalizationmethod algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
      <ds:signaturemethod algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1">
        <ds:reference uri="#pfx66175dea-cec7-2bef-e3e3-41f93e072905">
          <ds:transforms>
            <ds:transform algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"> 
            </ds:transform>
          </ds:transforms>
          <ds:digestmethod algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1">. 
            <ds:digestvalue>Vfgm3qESZl51Tly2gUEosIerE8I=</ds:digestvalue> 
          </ds:digestmethod>
        </ds:reference>
      </ds:signaturemethod>
    </ds:canonicalizationmethod>
  </ds:signedinfo>
  <ds:signaturevalue>...</ds:signaturevalue>
  <ds:keyinfo>
    <wsse:securitytokenreference>
      <wsse:reference valuetype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" uri="#pfx3e1c9c60-13a0-7434-f769-a25570eda011">. 
      </wsse:reference>
    </wsse:securitytokenreference>
  </ds:keyinfo>
</ds:signature>
```

PHP which is generating the above (not using a WSDL, or SOAP client, rolling my own DOM Document):

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$envelope = $dom->createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope', 'soap:Envelope');
$envelope->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:v1',$serviceContract);
$envelope->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:v11','$serviceContract');

//.
//.
//I create and append the <soap:body> here
//.
//.

$objWSA = new WSASoap($dom);
$objWSA->addAction($action);
$objWSA->addTo($to);

//Not needed so commenting out
//$objWSA->addMessageID();
//$objWSA->addReplyTo();

$dom = $objWSA->getDoc();

$objWSSE = new WSSESoap($dom);
/* DONT Sign all headers only want to sign specific one could this be at issue?*/
$objWSSE->signBody = false;
$objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, ['type'=>'private']);
$objKey->loadKey($this->wexSoapX509PrivateKey, true);
        
$objWSSE->signSoapDoc($objKey,['signSpecificHeaders' => ["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" =>["To" => true] ] ]);

/* Add certificate (BinarySecurityToken) to the message and attach pointer to Signature */
$token = $objWSSE->addBinaryToken(file_get_contents($privKey));
$objWSSE->attachTokentoSig($token);
$objWSSE->addTimestamp(3000);

//move the security header around because they were specific about order. Might mess with canonicalization? But even without this the same thing happens
$header = $envelope->firstChild;
$action = $header->firstChild;
$security = $header->lastChild;
$header->removeChild($security);
$header->insertBefore($security, $action);
$request = $objWSSE->saveXML();
var_dump($request);
```

I'm stumped. The best I can figure is that something in the order I have done things is off, such that the structure before signing is off and a child gets appended wrong or something.

Can anyone see why that would be happening?

Comment: You have placed many questions with the code, I'd suggest you reduce it to the minimal example that reproduces your issue (also compare [mre]). For the question if you can sign only some but not all headers: I don't know, but it should be possible to reference the specs for this point. It must not mean that the implementation you use also then supports it but then you could have clarified already if it is possible by the book at least (or not). For the question about the order: It remains undefined to whom you refer to when you write "they" and what the specifics are "they were about".